# Detecting shadowing of member variables

Tags: c++, initialization

I have a class A with a member:

```
std::shared_ptr<class B> m_mySharedPtr;
```

I have an Init method:

```
A::Init()
{
  std::shared_ptr<class B> m_mySharedPtr = m_factory->CreateMySharedPtr();
}
```

It took me some time to realize that after my Init the shared_ptr is Empty.
That is because I re-define the member, treated as a local and thus released when out of A::Init() scope.

I meant to write:

```
A::Init()
{
  m_mySharedPtr = m_factory->CreateMySharedPtr();
}
```

Why did the compiler not complain? At least a warning?
Something like "member re-definition."

Is it indeed valid/useful in a particular case?

Maybe my warning level is too low.

Thanks,

Vincent

Comment: You're not redefining a member, since you're not defining a member inside the function.

Comment: Also, this question has unnecessarily confusing title and tags. It has nothing to do with shared pointers.

Comment: I've hidden (not redefined) a member variable when I'm trying to test something, but I always remove it before anybody else sees it.

Comment: it is related somehow to shared pointers because with another type, like native (example int) you get a warning:
"warning C4189: 'm_myInt' : local variable is initialized but not referenced" since I am not doing anything else in the init.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using GCC or Clang, then use the `-Wshadow` flag.  You get compiler output like this:

```
test.cc:5:7: warning: declaration shadows a field of 'A' [-Wshadow]
                std::shared_ptr<class B> m_mySharedPtr = m_factory->CreateMySharedPtr();
                                         ^
test.cc:2:15: note: previous declaration is here
        std::shared_ptr<class B> m_mySharedPtr;
```

- Reference: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.2/gcc/Warning-Options.html#Warning-Options.