# How to explicitly initialize a member which does not have a default constructor?

Tags: c++, oop

I have drawn a very simple graph to follow my description below, hope it helps:
[image]

My problem:
I need an object of **classC** in **classA**. The problem is **classC** needs two arguments in the constructor, which can only be created in **classB** (after calling an init method in **classB**, but for now, assume this init method is called early enough. Further, I have a **classD**, which inherits from **classB** (which holds the two arguments needed). And last, I also need an object of **classA** in **classD**.

As said, I need an object of **classC** in **classA**. I can't just create it directly in **classA**, since I would not be able to provide the necessary arguments (which are created in **classB**). My idea was to create an object of **classC** in **classB** (since this is the only way (I guess) to initialize the object with the arguments). Then, since I need an object of **classA** in **classD**, and **classD** inherits from **classB**, I thought that I can grab the object of **classC** (created in **classB**) in **classD** (should be possible due to the inheritance, shouldn't it?) and pass it to **classA** as an argument of its constructor. (I don't want that **classA** inherits from classD.)

Is this a good idea? In my inexperienced eyes, it looks very confusing and until now, I couldn't manage to get it working (maybe it's not possible, or maybe I just didn't set up everything correctly). But I would be happy with any advice on how to solve this problem more elegantly. I appreciate any help.

### EDIT

Thanks for all the answers! I have tried to simplify the code as much as possible. I get the error, that the constructor must explicitly initialize the member of classC (see classA.cpp and classB.cpp comment). But the necessary arguments to initialize an object of classC are created during the `init` function call in classB. What is the problem here, i.e. why do I get these errors? I thought, that when I pass an object of a class as an argument for the constructor of another class, I don't need to instantiate the class again?
Any help is really appreciated!

**Class A**

`classA.h`

```
#include <classC.h>

classA
{
    public:
        explicit classA(classC classC_object);
        void doSomething();
}
```

`classA.cpp`

```
#include <classA.h>

classA::classA(classC classC_object) // Error: constructor for classC must explicitly initialize the member classC_object which does not have a default constructor
{
}

void classA::doSomething()
{
    classC_object.someMethod();
}
```

**class B**

`classB.h`

```
classB
{
    public:
        classB(int argc, char** argv);

        void init();

        classC classC_object;
}
```

`classB.cpp`

```
#include <classB.h>

classB::classB(int argc, char** argv) // Error: constructor for classB must explicitly initialize the member classC_object which does not have a default constructor
{
}

void classB::init()
{
    some_type_specificly_created_in_classB arg;
    classC classC_object(arg);
}
```

**Class C**

`classC.h`

```
classC
{
    public:
        classC(const some_type_specificly_created_in_classB& arg);
        // some methods I want to access in classA
        void someMethod();
}
```

**Class D**

`classD.h`

```
#include <classB.h>
#include <classA.h>

classD
{
    public:
        classD(int argc, char** argv);

    private:
        classB classB_object;
        classA* classA_object;
}
```

`classD.cpp`

```
#include <classD.h>
#include <classA.h>

classD::classD(int argc, char** argv) : classB_object(argc, argv)
{
    classA_object = new classA(classB_object.classC_object);
}
```

Comment: What's your question?  When you instantiate an object D, class B is created, which creates class C, so you can pass that to class A...

Comment: Show a motivating example with real class names.

Comment: The plan looks good to me. Why don't you add your best attempt at getting it working? (I tried converting your description to code, and everything fell into place for me. So I would need to see your try to see where you are having an issue.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not match your description (for example, `D` does not inherit from `B` in your code). There are also a number of compiler errors originating with sloppy syntax, such as the lack of the keyword `class` in your class definitions. Still, I suppose that is enough of a starting point with which to work.

Overall, I suspect your design has weaknesses that should be addressed, particularly with regard to `classB::init()`. However, the question does not (and possibly should not) have enough context to determine that. So I will go through your classes in an order that makes sense to me.

---

Let's start with `classC`, which to me looks like the starting point for this setup. What you have looks reasonable. The class has a public constructor taking a parameter that can be obtained only from `classB`, which almost matches your description. Your description does mention *two* parameters, rather than just one, but that is probably a trivial difference. Just consider flagging the constructor `explicit`.

---

The next class I would look at is `classA`. Your description states the need for "an object of **classC** in **classA**", yet this seems to have been overlooked in your implementation. On the other hand, `classA::doSomething` references an undefined variable (`classC_object`). My conclusion is that `classC_object` was supposed to be a member of `A` and of type `classC`. So I'll go ahead and add that field to your class definition.

```
class classA
{
        classC classC_object;
    public:
        explicit classA(classC classC_object) : classC_object(std::move(classC_object)) {}
        void doSomething()
        {
            classC_object.someMethod();
        }
};
```

Both your description and your code say that `classA` cannot construct a `classC` object. I would point out, though, that it could if given a `some_type_specificly_created_in_classB` object. Naturally, this would not be a good option if it breaks encapsulation.

---

Now we come to `classB`, where we face a conundrum. You have declared a member of type `classC`, yet that member cannot be constructed until `init()` is called. It's not clear how to resolve this without better context. From your description, I had thought that the construction parameters would be stored in the object of `classB`, not an entire `classC` object. Is this an optimization to avoid constructing the `classC` object multiple times? Does each `classB` object need its `classC` object for other reasons? If both answers are "no", you might want to replace `classC classC_object` with `some_type_specificly_created_in_classB arg` and add a member function that constructs and returns a `classC` object based upon `arg`.

If there is a reason for `init()` to construct the `classC` object, this can be done. First, though, get rid of the do-nothing line that constructs a *local* object named `classC_object` – this does not affect the member with the same name, and in fact this declaration shadows the member (see also [Detecting shadowing of member variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773732/detecting-shadowing-of-member-variables)). Once that's done, you could change your data member to a pointer of some sort. This pointer would be set to null in the constructor, which means you would also need to decide what to do if the `classC` object is requested before `init()` is called. I'll go with calling `init()` at that point. (I don't know if this is plausible since I don't know why `init()` is not called from the constructor. It takes no parameters, so it seems safe to call.)

```
#include <memory>

class classB
{
        std::unique_ptr<classC> classC_pointer;  // <-- pointer, and private.

    public:
        classB(int argc, char** argv) : classC_pointer()
        {
             // do something
             // ** Why is init() not part of this constructor? **
        }

        void init()
        {
            some_type_specificly_created_in_classB arg;
            std::make_unique<classC>(arg).swap(classC_pointer); // <-- construct classC object
        }

        const classC & getC()
        {
            if ( !classC_pointer ) // If the pointer is null
                init();
            return *classC_pointer;
        }
};
```

Again, there are other options for what to do here. In particular, I would see if the functionality of `init()` can be done in the constructor. If the functionality can be called from the initializer list, it might be possible to go back to having a `classC` member instead of a pointer. The pointer approach might be one of the more complicated possibilities. If you find yourself needing this pointer approach, you might want to re-evaluate your design; there might be a better way to divide up the tasks.

---

Finally, there is `classD`. Your description says that this should inherit from `classB`, and I'd stick with that since it makes it easier to ensure the initializations are done in the required order. (Base classes are initialized before members.) There's not much else to do to your definition other than make sure the parameters get passed to `classB`. Style-wise, I would give `classA_object` (which would be more accurately called `classA_pointer`) a value in the initializer list.

```
class classD : public classB
{
    public:
        classD(int argc, char** argv) : classB(argc, argv),
            classA_object{nullptr}
        {
            init();  // <-- You did say this would be called early enough!
            classA_object = new classA(getC());
        }

    private:
        classA* classA_object;
};
```

Note that it looks like the only reason for making `classA_object` a pointer is so that `init()` can be called in time. If that functionality could be moved into the constructor of `classB`, then perhaps `classA_object` could be changed into a `classA` object instead of a `classA` pointer? Actually, the approach I took in `getC()` would allow this anyway.

```
class classD : public classB
{
    public:
        classD(int argc, char** argv) : classB(argc, argv),
            classA_object(getC())
        {}

    private:
        classA classA_object; // <-- no longer a pointer
};
```